# How to get CTRL+T hotkey to work on Chrome Incognito?

Tags: google-chrome

I use <kbd>CTRL</kbd> <kbd>T</kbd> to open a new tab in Google Chrome.

I also often use incognito mode.

This hotkey does not appear to work in incognito mode.

How can I get this hotkey to work?

Edit: I am using Windows 10 and Chrome 108.0.5359.125.

Comment: Works for me, but no idea why it doesn't work for you.

Comment: @harrymc Interesting. Perhaps it's the OS. I'm using Windows 10.

Comment: I'm also on Windows 10. Try perhaps *Settings > Advanced > Reset and clean up*, or even reinstall Chrome (save at least the bookmarks, if not the entire profile folder).

Comment: @harrymc Thanks, you lead me on the right track, it was an extension that caused the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The extension [Duplicate Tab Shortcut](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/duplicate-tab-shortcut/klehggjefofgiajjfpoebdidnpjmljhb?hl=en) was the culprit, however, I believe it is still a browser bug that is causing this.

This extension allows me to remap CTRL+T to open a new tab to the right (as opposed to the built-in mechanism which opens the tab at the very end).

[image]

The extension was disabled in incognito mode, however, the original CTRL+T chrome keymapping remained unbound (must be a bug in Chrome?).

The solution for me was to enable the extension in incognito mode.

It would have been nice if chrome didn't unset key bindings in incognito mode for extensions that aren't even enabled in incognito -- sounds a bit ridiculous to me.

Comment: Extensions are disabled in Incognito mode, so this extension should not have been active.

Comment: @harrymc Yep, it wasn't active. When the extension is active, Chrome is unbinding the native CTRL+T hotkey. But for some reason, when the extension is not active, Chrome still unbinds the native CTRL+T hotkey, and that's what's caused the glitch in incognito mode. I would probably classify this as a bug in Chrome.

Comment: It's not a bug if it's only happening on your computer.

Comment: @harrymc I think it's a bug with the chrome extension api. So it would go unnoticed unless someone has an extension like this installed.